# Laravel 5.2 : Authentication auth::attempt returns false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on authentication module, I have this weird problem, `Auth::attempt` returns false, Where my username and password is correct.

The same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111770/laravel-4-authattempt-always-returns-false) is asked here also but that is not addressing my problems and that question is about laravel 4, I have tried their methods but still not working.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
$user = array(
    'name' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Input::get('password')
);
if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
    return "ok.";
} else {
    dd($user);
}
```

The else part returns :

```
array:2 [▼
  "name" => "ali"
  "password" => "ali"
]
```

Which means the `name` and the password is correct.

I am using laravel 5.2 and in my `users` table the password is not hashed and there is no `remember_token` means i have created the `user` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will not work because auth::attempt converts password to hash using bcrypt, and looks for that hash in users table to match.

in short the password should be a hash stored in database table for auth::attempt to work.

that is why your if() condition failing.

below is from laravel 5.2 docs

> The attempt method accepts an array of key / value pairs as its first
>   argument. The values in the array will be used to find the user in
>   your database table. So, in the example above, the user will be
>   retrieved by the value of the email column. If the user is found, the
>   hashed password stored in the database will be compared with the
>   hashed password value passed to the method via the array. If the two
>   hashed passwords match an authenticated session will be started for
>   the user.
>
> The attempt method will return true if authentication was successful.
>   Otherwise, false will be returned.

Comment: If you are in an early stage of development and you have not build a register functionality yet but still want to test authenticate you can echo a password by Hash::make('password') or bcrypt('password) (I htink) and insert it manually into your database.

Comment: @Thomas Van der Veen, you are right , still the password needs to be hashed to use.

Comment: Ohhhhhh Thank you guys. That was my fault.

Comment: you can use bcrypt(password) to store password as hash in database and then use auth::attempt

Answer (score 2):

the attempt method hash the password before comparing it to the database, meaning that if the password in your database is not hashed, it will not match.