# Laravel after login keep back to login form

Tags: php, laravel-5

Good day i'm learning about laravel 5 , Now i'm trying to create a login. But, my login keep back to my login form instead of go to `HomeController`. Here is my script

```
class Loginsite extends Controller
{

public function index(){

    return view::make("Login");

}
function loginproses(Request $request){
    extract(Maincontroller::populateform());    
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     $userdata = array(
                'username' =>$username,
                'password'=>$password
            );

       if(Auth::attempt($userdata) == true){
            return redirect('/');
       }else{
            return redirect('/loginsite')->with('status', 'Username atau Password salah');
       }

    }
}
```

Routes

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/logout', 'Loginsite@logout');
Route::post('/Loginsite/loginproses', 'Loginsite@loginproses');
Route::post('/Loginsite/register', 'Loginsite@register');
Route::get('/Loginsite/', 'Loginsite@index');
Route::get('/confirm/{username}/{random}', 'Loginsite@confirm')->name('confirm');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

and this is `HomeController`

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        echo "Logged In";
    }
}
```

when i try `dd(Auth::attempt($userdata) );` i get `true`

I'm using custom table

```
   'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Loginmodel::class,
            'table' => 'Userlogin'
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

MainController

```
class Maincontroller extends Controller
{
    //
    public static function populateform(){
        $input = Input::all();
        foreach(array_keys($input) as $key){
            $populate[$key] = $input[$key];
        }
         return $populate;
    }
}
```

A test from submit

```
dd(Maincontroller::populateform());
```

return

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "YQgV3t1dc0GZrIdPboZvflBDxs7KXCEdcQkFDrD4"
  "username" => "boby"
  "password" => "1234"
]
```

Thanks in advance , sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){ 
return redirect('/home'); 

}else{ 
return redirect('/')->with('status', 'Username atau Password salah'); 
}
```

try removing the true and keep it simple and check

Comment: Still get redirected :(

Comment: tell me how are you getting the username and password? how are you taking it in the controller

Comment: I get it from user submit

Comment: no means in the controller you are using $username but i cant see anything for getting it like $username = $request->username, just try to print_r($userdata) and see what username and password are you getting

Comment: oh, i create a simple function in MainController

Comment: first of all try to print in the login controller to check if data is passed properly or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148964/discussion-between-yvs1102-and-exprator).

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be just with `$username` and `$password`, `password` need to be hashed. You should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37455780/5350773) as well as read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users) carefully.

I also want to suggest you some edits in code, which are important for simplification.

as in `web.php` you can see there is name for Home Page Route

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Always refer that name, this will be helpful in avoiding base_url problem if any occurs or if you decide to change the route itself, you'll just need to change url which referred by name everywhere you use.

Routes

```
Route::post('/Loginsite/loginproses', 'Loginsite@loginproses')->name('login_process');
Route::get('/Loginsite/', 'Loginsite@index')->name('loginsite_index');
```

LoginSite Controller

```
if(Auth::attempt($userdata) == true){
            return redirect()->route('home');
       }else{
            return redirect()->route('loginsite_index')->with('status', 'Username atau Password salah');
       }
```

Login Form

use `route()` in action method with route name

```
<form action="{{ route('login_process') }}" method="post">
....
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think my problem is in this part `$request-> ...`

Comment: try `print_r($request->all())` to check if you are receiving inputs correctly. Problem may be also with password check, because Laravel stores password in hashes (check database table to confirm this).

Comment: I get this array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "YQgV3t1dc0GZrIdPboZvflBDxs7KXCEdcQkFDrD4"
  "username" => "boby"
  "password" => "1234"
]

Comment: what about database table.. password column has password as it is or hashed..?

Answer (score 0):

Add back slash before Auth::attempt($userdata) if auth not found also remove to check with true.

```
if(\Auth::attempt($userdata)){
        return redirect('/');
   }else{
        return redirect('/loginsite')->with('status', 'Username atau Password salah');
   }
```